# DataForm remove the + & - in Silverlight 5

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, silverlight, xaml

I have a sample dataform and I would like to remove the ability to add and remove records from the form.
Apparently in Silverlight 3 there were 2 attributes to the dataform "CanUserAddItem" & "CanUserDeleteItem". Those attributes don't seem to exist anymore.

Any suggestion on how to make those buttons go away!

cheers,

Comment: What are you using as the ItemsSource?

Comment: @cadrell0 I am using an observable collection. Which contains a list of my own objects retrieve through a SOAP ws.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can change the ObserableCollection you are using as the ItemsSource to a [ReadOnlyObserableCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668620.aspx) I think the DataForm is see this and remove the Add and Delete buttons.

**Edit**

Going a little Googling, I found a property named `CommandButtonVisibility`.  I haven't upgraded to Silverlight 5 yet, so I don't know if this is still in the DataForm, but it might work for you.

Comment: Hi, I would still like to be able to edit within the form wouldn't using that datastructure prevent me from using the edit capabilities of the dataform ?

Comment: You will not be able to change the collection itself, but you will still be able to change properties on the items in the collection.